# video upload, only uploads videos under 20 seconds

Tags: php, iphone, objective-c, ios, post

Alright, so heres my problem, i need my user to be able to upload a video, the video can be any size, so i have written a php script to deal with placing the file in the correct place..Here is my code:

```
-(IBAction)upload:(id)sender{
[self post:webdata];
}
```

webdata is the video data, here is the code where i set that up:

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info{ 
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
//assign the mediatype to a string 
//check the media type string so we can determine if its a video
    NSURL *videoURL = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL];
    webData = [[NSData alloc]init];
    webData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:videoURL];
    //[self post:webData];
    video = 1;
    upload.hidden = NO;

    ImagesCopy = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"1", nil];
[tableview reloadData];


 }
```

Okay so now i have the webdata all done, now i need to upload the data by calling `[self post:webdata` as posted above

```
- (void)post:(NSData *)fileData
```

{

```
NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithContentsOfFile:[self saveUserLogin]];

int test;
NSString *string = [array objectAtIndex:3];
test = [string intValue];
test++;
NSData *videoData = fileData;
NSString *urlString = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"http://www.site.com/members/uploadMovie.php?&username=%@", [array objectAtIndex:0]];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc]initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString] cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:100000000000];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
NSString *boundary = [NSString stringWithString:@"---------------------------14737809831466499882746641449"];
NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@", boundary];
[request addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
NSString *postName = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"userfile\"; filename=\"vid%i.mov\"\r\n", test];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:postName] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[NSData dataWithData:videoData]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[request setHTTPBody:body];


//NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];
//NSString *returnString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:returnData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication]setNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible:YES];
NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc]initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
if (connection) {
    responceData = [NSMutableData data];

}
else{
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"Well something went wrong, make sure you have a valid internet connection and try again" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
    [alert show];
}
//  NSLog(@"%@", returnString);

NSArray *values = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects: [array objectAtIndex:0],[array objectAtIndex:1], [array objectAtIndex:2], [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", test], nil];
[values writeToFile:[self saveUserLogin] atomically:YES];
```

}

Okay, so now i need to call in some methods:

```
    - (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {
[responceData appendData:data];

}

    -(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didSendBodyData (NSInteger)bytesWritten totalBytesWritten:(NSInteger)totalBytesWritten 
totalBytesExpectedToWrite:(NSInteger)totalBytesExpectedToWrite{

if([connecting isAnimating]){
    [connecting stopAnimating];
[connectingImage removeFromSuperview];
[connecting removeFromSuperview];
}
float progress = [[NSNumber numberWithInteger:totalBytesWritten] floatValue];
float total = [[NSNumber numberWithInteger: totalBytesExpectedToWrite] floatValue];
progressForUpload.progress = progress/total;

 }

 - (void) connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {

NSString* responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responceData     encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(responseString);
progressForUpload.progress = 0;

[ImagesCopy removeObjectAtIndex:0];
[tableview reloadData];

if (ImagesCopy.count == 0) {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication]setNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible:NO];

    [self.delegate didFinishController:self];
    }
}

- (void) connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {
[[UIApplication sharedApplication]setNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible:NO];
UIAlertView *erroragain = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"Something went wrong, this might be a server problem, log out and try again, if its still not working, wait a hour and try again" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
[erroragain show];
 }
```

So this code runs fine, the video gets uploaded (if its under 20 seconds), now take a look at my php code:

```
<?php


$dbc = mysql_connect('hosting', 'user', 'pass');
if(!$dbc){
    die('not connected : ' . mysql_error());
}

$db_selected = mysql_select_db("db", $dbc);
if(!$db_selected){
        die("could not connect to DB : " . mysql_error());  
}

$username = $_GET['username'];

$check = mysql_query("SELECT video FROM members WHERE username='$username'");

$findMem = mysql_num_rows($check);

if($findMem > 0){
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($check) or die(mysql_error())){

$vid = $row['video'];

$vid = $vid + 1;

mysql_query("UPDATE members SET video='$vid'
WHERE username='$username'");

$uploaddir = './'.$username.'/default/';
$file = basename($_FILES['userfile']['name']);
$uploadfile = $uploaddir . $file;
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) {
    echo "done";


   }
   else{
       echo "error";
   }
}
}
?>
```

So i dont really get the problem, if it uploads videos under 20 seconds, it should be able to do longer right?

If someone could please help me figure out whats wrong with this, i need to be able to upload bigger videos, i have tried calling the `sleep(5)` in the php code to see if maybe the file just needed some time to process, didnt work.

Thanks,
Jacob

Comment: "able to do longer" ? please explain .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you are hitting either the file upload size limit, the execution time limit, the memory limit, or disk space.  You can change these in PHP.ini.

Also, you are **wide open** to SQL injection, and you **will be hacked** if you don't learn to do prepared queries with PDO, or at least escape your data.

Comment: Yep you were right. Can you possibly point me in the right direction to secure my sql?